# SUM multiple columns across multiple tables grouping on date

Tags: sql

I have a sales and expenses table with rows similar to this

### SALES

```
invoiced_on | total | ....
---------------------------
2010-10-01  | 500.00
2010-10-09  | 700.00
...
```

### EXPENSES

```
submitted_on | amount
---------------------
2010-10-01   | 100.00
2010-10-09   | 200.00
...
```

Ideally I would select three columns:

- week
- sales_total
- expenses_total

I'm not familiar with how to perform group_by on multiple aggregated columns.

Comment: What are you expecting in the `week` column for output?  For what database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same solution as I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228926/mysql-query-help/4228988#4228988)

The trick is to calculate the different totals first and then combine them into a single record.

Answer (score 0):

Should work in MS-SQL, but just typed in and not tested

```
select DATEPART (WW,x.transDate) as WeekNum,sum(x.SalesAmt) as Sales_total,sum(x.expenseAmt) as expenses_total
from 
(
select invoiced_on as Transdate,amount as SalesAmt,0 as ExpenseAmt 
from Sales
union
select submitted_on as Transdate,0 as SalesAmt,amount as ExpenseAmt 
from expenses
) x
group by DATEPART ( WW , transDate )
```